# How to pass parameter info async queue saturated or unsaturated?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
module.exports = Client;

function Client (info) {
    this.concurrency = info.concurrency;
    this.queue = async.queue(data, this.concurrency);
    this.logger = info.logger;
    this.queue.saturated = function() {
        this.logger.info('The queue has been saturated');
    }
    this.messagesQueue.unsaturated = function() {
        this.logger.info('The queue is unsaturated');
    }
};
```

Running the code I get an error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined`

I am not sure how to pass `this.logger` into the saturated and unsaturated methods?

Comment: Use arrow functions to keep the context: (eg: `this.queue.saturated = () => {...}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `this` inside `saturated` or `unsaturated` points to the function itself.

So you can do 3 things,

**1)** In your client class set a variable which point to `this` and use it.

```
function Client (info) {
    const that = this;
    this.queue.saturated = function() {
        that.logger.info('The queue has been saturated');
    }
};
```

**2)** Bind `this`: You can bind the `this` inside the function to the `this` of the `Client` context.

```
function Client (info) {
    this.queue.saturated = (function() {
        this.logger.info('The queue has been saturated');
    }).bind(this);
};
```

**3)** Use arrow functions: Arrow functions do not bind `this`. Read it as, there **IS NO** `this` variable inside the `saturated` or `unsaturated` function when you declare it using the arrow function. So when you access `this` from inside the function it uses the `Client` as `this` just like a simple closure variable.

```
function Client (info) {
    this.queue.saturated = () => {
        this.logger.info('The queue has been saturated');
    }
};
```